# Possible deadlock in a swagger python API

Tags: python, flask, swagger

In a swagger python API, let's call it 'A', when a POST is performed to it, this request is executed at some point:

```
postRequestESServer = requests.post(URL+'api/es/session', json.dumps(Trigger), headers=headers)
```

Now this request waits for a response. However this request triggers another component (answering at `/api/es/session`) that tries to PUT on the same 'A', API.

The result it that the PUT request is not returning, and my debugging shows that until the first hanging request from POST returns, the respective PUT function is not even called.

From my understanding the hanging POST request, returns because of a timeout. So my question is, can't swagger handle 2 API calls at the same time? Or python/flask?

EDIT: libraries used in the main app (called app.py):

```
import connexion
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson import json_util
from flask import Flask
from flask import g
from flask import jsonify
from flask import json
from flask import request
from flask import url_for
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template
from flask import make_response
import hashlib
import string
import random
import requests
```

Comment: Let me guess: you are running the *single threaded* Flask development server?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not the owner of the API or the server, i'm just the tester but I edited the question with the imports in the app.py file

Comment: Without the actual way the API served and all related code we can not reproduce the error. And AFAIR it is sufficient for a tester to report the error and let the person(s) responsible take action.

Comment: There is no error, however I googled 'single threaded Flask development server' and I found out that if you add `threaded=true` in the `app.run()` function, then it no longer deadlocks